# erase ubuntu and reinstall will it affect windows and other windows partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am trying to install a fresh version of Ubuntu in my computer without touching the windows 10 dual boot!

In the Installation Type, the first option seems exactly what i wanted to do.

[image]

My question is, is this feature is safe to use? because i don't want to lose any windows files and other NTFS partitions on the hard-disk. Please eliminate my confusion.

Note as that i dont need any files or media which are in the ubuntu partition, Thanks.

Comment: In short - no it won't affect your windows partition.

Comment: Thanks, what does the warning window says in this line: "SCSI1 (0,0,0)(sda)" what it means.

Comment: Stop, there's a bug 1265192 , the reinstall wipes the whole disk.

Comment: Shit .. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192 seems old now, dosent fixed yet? !!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's saying that the partition that you have created as logical, i.e,

`/dev/sda7` which is of type swap and

the partition `/dev/sda8` of type ext4

will be formatted and made clean to make space for the new installation of Ubuntu OS.

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for then, please accept the answer by ticking the tick symbol beside the answer (right-side).

Comment: sure, just give me 5 more minutes :=)

Answer (score 2):

Can confirm, used the first option of "Erase Ubuntu 16.04 and Reinstall".
Afterwards my partition with Ubuntu was formatted and the Windows 10 partition was untouched.