# Use Linux without wiping Windows. Preferrable option?

Tags: 22.04, xubuntu

[image: Reference Image]

I would like to use Ubuntu without deleting or erasing my Windows partition. Which option should I choose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [erase ubuntu and reinstall will it affect windows and other windows partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698318/erase-ubuntu-and-reinstall-will-it-affect-windows-and-other-windows-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

### Erase Ubuntu 22.04.3 and reinstall:

Erases Ubuntu(Only) and reinstalls in that erased space

### Install Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS alongside Ubuntu 22.04 LTS:

Creates a new partition with the provided free space and installs in that partition.

### Erase disk and install Ubuntu

Erases the whole hard drive and installs Ubuntu

### Something else

Displays a disk partition manager to choose the disk partition layout you would like to have.

I Recommend to backup your system on the existing install before you proceed any further. For your requirements, I would suggest using the 1st option.

But there are alternatives to this, such as doing `sudo do-release-upgrade` in your existing installation. Make sure you have set `Prompt=normal` in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`. Simply edit it using `sudo gedit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and saving it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.